# decomposition of permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

It seems that we can decompose permutation groups to wreath product of primitive permutations, much in the same way that abstract groups are decomposed to semi-direct product of simple groups.

However, I have a hard time finding a basic reference explaining this in more detail in a simple language.

**Can you suggest some references for a beginner?**

Here are the sort of questions I need answered by a reference:

- Are there other decompositions for permutaion groups?
- An intuitive explanation of primitive wreath product.
- The relation between the decomposition of abstract and permutation groups (if any)

One relevant online resource I could find is [this paper](http://www.austms.org.au/Publ/Jamsa/V80P1/pdf/r67.pdf), but only the early part of the paper seems basic and relevant.

I also have access to the Dixon and Mortimer's "Permutation Groups", but I couldn't find explicit discussion of these dicomposition ideas in that book.

Comment: The first sentence "it seems" is not that clear. For instance, partition a set of size $2n$ into components of size 2. The stabilizer of this partition is a wreath product, of order $2^nn!$. It has a subgroup of index two, generated by $S_n$ and the $n$-tuples of size zero. For $n\ge 3$, this subgroup does not seem to split nontrivially as wreath product.

Comment: "It has a subgroup of index two, generated by Sn and the n-tuples of size zero" not sure what you mean by n-tuples of size zero. Wouldn't the first step in the decomposition of your example, give us $C_2$ and $S_n$? My claim is my understanding of what appears at the paper that I linked. Any clarification or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: of *sum* zero, sorry. This is the unique $S_n$-invariant hyperplane in $C_2^n$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean by that sentence (it might be because I'm coming from a different field)